# How to create a link aggregation (NIC TEAM) between bare metal, with Hyper-V 2016, and the switch

Tags: bonding, network-teaming, hyper-v-server-2016

I started using Hyper-V a short time ago, I only have experience with ESXi. I'm trying to do a link aggregation with the 4 network interfaces between bare metal with Hyper-V and the switch. I've already learned how to make a Hyper-V NIC TEAM to offer to the VMs the aggregate interface, but now I'm trying to make the NIC TEAM in bare metal (server <=> switch). See the image where I want to make the NIC TEAM. Does not Hyper-V 2016 (core, not GUI) allow this?
(The switch accepts link aggregation.)

[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXN9y.png)

Comment: Now the advice. I think of making a NIC TEAM between the bare metal HP and my switch or rather make a NIC TEAM between Hyper-V and VM. For example, my bare metal has 4 NICs and I want to do 2-2 aggregation and connect two VMs in each aggregation. What would be better, do the link aggregation between Hyper-V and the switch, or do the link aggregation between Hyper-V and VMs (using the virtual switch + aggregation concept)?

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 (Server Manager):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/nic-teaming/create-a-new-nic-team

Method 2 (PowerShell):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netlbfo/?view=win10-ps&viewFallbackFrom=winserverr2-ps

Answer (score 0):

I think the New-NetlbfoTeam powershell cmdlet would work for you.

Something like this:

```
New-NetlbfoTeam -Name Team1 -TeamMembers NIC1,NIC2 -TeamingMode SwitchIndependant -LoadBalancingAlgorithm Dynamic
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netlbfo/New-NetLbfoTeam?view=win10-ps